# How to manage MySql Database after the storage quata exceeds?

Tags: mysql, linux, database

I've hosted one of my apps in Linux hosting package.  Hosting site only provide 250 MB storage for single MySql Databas.  How can I manage database which exceeds the 250 MB storage?

Comment: Not Memory , Storage.

Comment: If you have 250 MB of storage, that's probably just what you get. If you can't compress it enough to make it fit, you'll probably just need to upgrade or change your hosting.

Comment: All packages are the same storage.  They told me that you can create another database.

Comment: There you go then - if it's 250MB *per database*, and you can create more than one, you could create more. It'd be a bit of a pain, but if for some reason you're stuck there, there's one workaround. Do what they said.

Comment: That I know.  Please carefully read my question, then give an answer.

Comment: Please don't be rude, and if that's the case, I'm not sure what your question is. You have X space. if you need more than X, you'll either have to go to another host that gives you more, or make your data fit in X space.

Comment: I've found another solution @mike.